# How to write the web view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make one webview controller and what I am doing, I just make a webview controller super class like this:

```

```
class YQTWebViewController: BaseViewController {
    var webview = WKWebView()
    var urlString: String?
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webview.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    webview.navigationDelegate = self
    view.addSubview(webview)
    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
    // 30 by 30
    let x = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width / 2 - 20
    let y = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width / 2 - 20
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 40, 40)
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

     guard urlString != nil else {
        return
     }
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString!)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webview.loadRequest(request)
```

}

```

And i just want to make subclass of YQTWebViewcontroller, and just override the urlString when finished the initialize the view controller, but I don't know where should I put my code. Can anybody give me some suggestion of that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain in deep..Can't understand what actually you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create selector method like loadUrlInWebview: which takes urlString as a parameter and put the loading Url code in this selector body. So your loading url body code should get removed from ViewDidLoad method and pass onto this selector. Call this method from your subclass passing the urlString as a parameter.

So put this code:

```
    func loadUrlInWebview(urlString: String!) {
    guard urlString != nil else {
    return
    }
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString!)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webview.loadRequest(request)        
     }
```

Call this from subclass method , passing URL as a param.

Answer (score 0):

```
import WebKit
class YQTWebViewController: UIViewController {
    var webview = WKWebView()
    var urlString: String?
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webview.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        //webview.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webview)
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
        // 30 by 30
        let x = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width / 2 - 20
        let y = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width / 2 - 20
        activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 40, 40)
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        guard urlString != nil else {
            return
        }
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString!)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webview.loadRequest(request)
    }

    class SubViewController : YQTWebViewController{


        override var urlString: String? {
            get {
                return self.urlString
            }
            set {
                self.urlString = newValue
            }
        }
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            urlString = "YOUR URL STRING"
        }
    }
```